# Best way to get the IP address of client is req.ip or req.connection.remoteAddress?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering what the best way to get the IP Address of a client from my express application is, as SOF and docs show `req.ip` & `req.connection.remoteAddress`. Not sure what the difference is and which is the one I should use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`req.ip` will try to resolve the actual client IP-address by also taking into account headers that are set by proxy servers indicating the origin (client) of the request (although this will only be done if the [`trust proxy`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table) setting is explicitly enabled).

`req.connection.remoteAddress` will contain the IP-address of the client making the request, which in case of a proxy server will be the proxy's IP-address and not the one from the client on whose behalf the proxy is forwarding the request.

If you're using a reverse proxy that is forwarding requests to your Express server, `req.ip` and enabling `trust proxy` is the best solution. Otherwise, just plain `req.ip` will still do.

Answer (score 7):

best way to get users IP is `req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;`

like this `var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;`

because may be you will use middleware (or most common used proxy) servers (like Cloudflare) for security reasons and if you use `req.connection.remoteAddress` it will send your middleware servers IP address everytime, but you can use x-forwarded-for header and `req.connection.remoteAddress` or `req.ip` together.

for more information read about [x-forwarded-for http header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

**EDIT**

as mentioned in comments below best practice to use `req.ip || req.connection.remoteAddress`; because even if you use app without proxy, in future you can use it with proxy, and with method above you can use your application without changing it.

Comment: I'm not using a proxy, so if not using a proxy which should I use, and also if I am using a proxy in the future which should I use? (if you can edit your answer to fit what I just asked it will help future people that run into the same problem.)

Comment: Be careful though, as I understand it the `x-forwaded-for` header may contain more than one ip (if your express app is behind a proxy for example). So I guess sticking to `req.ip` is the way to go

Comment: @lascort, thanks for comment, I learned too and updated my answer for other users.